# On hover or click to display the respective image

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a list and when user hover or click on the list then respective image will display on right side.

Below script I am using for add and remove active class from li tags.

```js
$(".listWrap ul li").hover(
  function() {
    $(this).addClass('active');
  },
  function() {
    if (!$(this).hasClass('clicked')) {
      $(this).removeClass('active');
    }
  }
);

$(".listWrap ul li").click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('clicked');
});
```

```css
.listWrap li.active a {
  color: #f00;
}

.hoverimg li {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">
<section class="">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-xxl-6 col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <div class="listWrap">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">qwerqwer</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">tyuityui</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">opoiuiop</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">mnbvzxcv</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">zxcmnbv</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">mnbvzxcv</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-xxl-6 col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <div class="listWrap position-relative">
          <div class="hoverimg">
            <ul>
              <li><img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/fa17fa/0011ff" alt=""></li>
              <li><img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000000/0011ff" alt=""></li>
              <li><img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/1ee81e/0011ff" alt=""></li>
              <li><img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/1e35e6/0011ff" alt=""></li>
              <li><img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/e6d620/0011ff" alt=""></li>
<li><img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/fff320/0011ff" alt=""></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably use the index to hide show images using `hide()`/`show()`:

```js
$('.listWrap ul li:eq(0)').addClass('active'); // add class on page load to the first linnk
$('.hoverimg ul li:eq(0)').show(); // show the first image li on page load
$(".listWrap ul li").hover(
  function() {
    $('.listWrap ul li').removeClass('active'); // remove class all of the link li elements
    $('.hoverimg ul li').hide(); // hide all image li elements
    $(this).addClass('active'); // add the class to the current element
    var idx = $(this).index()-1; 
    $('.hoverimg ul li:eq('+idx+')').show(); // show the respective image li element
  }
);
```

```css
.listWrap li.active a {
  color: #f00;
}

.hoverimg li {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">
<section class="">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-xxl-6 col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <div class="listWrap">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">qwerqwer</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">tyuityui</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">opoiuiop</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">mnbvzxcv</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">zxcmnbv</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">mnbvzxcv</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-xxl-6 col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <div class="listWrap position-relative">
          <div class="hoverimg">
            <ul>
              <li><img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/fa17fa/0011ff" alt=""></li>
              <li><img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000000/0011ff" alt=""></li>
              <li><img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/1ee81e/0011ff" alt=""></li>
              <li><img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/1e35e6/0011ff" alt=""></li>
              <li><img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/e6d620/0011ff" alt=""></li>
              <li><img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/fff320/0011ff" alt=""></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I have equal number of elements. I forgot to update it. Let me update it

Comment: I added last image in the question. I tried your answer. 1) it's removing the active class from the li 2) It's displaying the last li image.

Comment: I checked again your answer after updating,Thanks for the answer but I am getting some issues, Can you help me? 1) If I hover all one by one then at the end I am not getting image. 2) onload last image displaying. I have to display first one

Comment: @user9437856, then what you want on mouse leave?

Comment: On page load i have to show the first li with first image and on leave last active li

Comment: @user9437856, in that case you do not need the second call back function (for mouse leave), updated the answer please check:)

Comment: @Manun, Yes, It's working perflectly for me. Thanks for the help. I want to know from where you learn the scripting? any video or any course?

Comment: @user9437856, I could not mention a single source as there are so many of them and but the most important thing is the exercise that helps me to clear things out:)