# On hover and click to display the image

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

A few days ago, I asked same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65548338/on-hover-or-click-to-display-the-respective-image/). I have to show the respective image when hover or click on the anchor tag and It's solved my issue.

Now, I am getting one more issue in this script. If I use same code one time then there is no issue but If I use same code twice or more then 2-3 times then I am getting the issues. I mean my code is not working properly.

```js
$('.listWrap ul li:eq(0)').addClass('active'); // add class on page load to the first linnk
$('.hoverimg ul li:eq(0)').show(); // show the first image li on page load
$(".listWrap ul li").hover(
  function() {
    $('.listWrap ul li').removeClass('active'); // remove class all of the link li elements
    $('.hoverimg ul li').hide(); // hide all image li elements
    $(this).addClass('active'); // add the class to the current element
    var idx = $(this).index() - 1;
    $('.hoverimg ul li:eq(' + idx + ')').show(); // show the respective image li element
  }
);
```

```css
.listWrap li.active a {
  color: #f00;
}

.hoverimg li {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">


<section class="">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-xxl-6 col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <div class="listWrap">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">qwerqwer</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">tyuityui</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">opoiuiop</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">mnbvzxcv</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">zxcmnbv</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">mnbvzxcv</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-xxl-6 col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <div class="listWrap position-relative">
          <div class="hoverimg">
            <ul>
              <li><img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/fa17fa/0011ff" alt=""></li>
              <li><img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000000/0011ff" alt=""></li>
              <li><img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/1ee81e/0011ff" alt=""></li>
              <li><img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/1e35e6/0011ff" alt=""></li>
              <li><img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/e6d620/0011ff" alt=""></li>
              <li><img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/fff320/0011ff" alt=""></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>


<section class="mt-5 pt-5">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-xxl-6 col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <div class="listWrap">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">qwerqwer</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">tyuityui</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">opoiuiop</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">mnbvzxcv</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">zxcmnbv</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">mnbvzxcv</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-xxl-6 col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <div class="listWrap position-relative">
          <div class="hoverimg">
            <ul>
              <li><img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/fa17fa/0011ff" alt=""></li>
              <li><img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000000/0011ff" alt=""></li>
              <li><img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/1ee81e/0011ff" alt=""></li>
              <li><img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/1e35e6/0011ff" alt=""></li>
              <li><img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/e6d620/0011ff" alt=""></li>
              <li><img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/fff320/0011ff" alt=""></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Please describe what you mean by not working. Playing with the code, I see mouse-move on the image invokes flickering, for instance. Is that the issue?

Comment: @KenY-N, If I hover in the first section of first li then it's changing the second section of the images. If user hover on first section of li then it should be display the image in first section only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have select the specific `li` elements with the selector -

```js
$('.listWrap ul li:eq(0)').addClass('active'); // add class on page load to the first linnk
$('.hoverimg ul li:eq(0)').show(); // show the first image li on page load
$(".listWrap ul li").hover(
  function() {
    $(this).closest('.listWrap').find('ul li').removeClass('active'); // remove class all of the link li elements
    const $hoverImage = $(this).closest('.row').find('.hoverimg')
    $hoverImage.find('ul li').hide();
    $(this).addClass('active'); // add the class to the current element
    var idx = $(this).index() - 1;
    $hoverImage.find('ul li:eq(' + idx + ')').show(); // show the respective image li element
  }
);
```

```css
.listWrap li.active a {
  color: #f00;
}

.hoverimg li {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">


<section class="">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-xxl-6 col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <div class="listWrap">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">qwerqwer</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">tyuityui</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">opoiuiop</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">mnbvzxcv</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">zxcmnbv</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">mnbvzxcv</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-xxl-6 col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <div class="listWrap position-relative">
          <div class="hoverimg">
            <ul>
              <li><img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/fa17fa/0011ff" alt=""></li>
              <li><img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000000/0011ff" alt=""></li>
              <li><img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/1ee81e/0011ff" alt=""></li>
              <li><img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/1e35e6/0011ff" alt=""></li>
              <li><img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/e6d620/0011ff" alt=""></li>
              <li><img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/fff320/0011ff" alt=""></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>


<section class="mt-5 pt-5">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-xxl-6 col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <div class="listWrap">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">qwerqwer</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">tyuityui</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">opoiuiop</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">mnbvzxcv</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">zxcmnbv</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">mnbvzxcv</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-xxl-6 col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <div class="listWrap position-relative">
          <div class="hoverimg">
            <ul>
              <li><img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/fa17fa/0011ff" alt=""></li>
              <li><img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000000/0011ff" alt=""></li>
              <li><img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/1ee81e/0011ff" alt=""></li>
              <li><img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/1e35e6/0011ff" alt=""></li>
              <li><img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/e6d620/0011ff" alt=""></li>
              <li><img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/fff320/0011ff" alt=""></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Let me check this.

Answer (score 1):

I've changed your code a little to make it simple. Ideas are as follows:

1. Hide all of your image elements using a `CSS` like this:

```css
.hoverimg ul li {
    display: none;
}
```

2. Add a `data-img` attribute in each of the lists in your `listWrap`, the value of which will correspond to the relative image like this:

```html
<li data-img="img1"><a href="javascript:void(0);">qwerqwer</a></li>
```

3. Add `mouseover` and `mouseout` events to each of the `listWrap ul` and toggle that specific image in this way:

```js
$(".listWrap ul").on("mouseover mouseout", "li", function () {
    $("#" + $(this).data("img")).toggle();
});
```

Here is the working example:

```js
$(".listWrap ul").on("mouseover mouseout", "li", function () {
    $("#" + $(this).data("img")).toggle();
});
```

```css
.listWrap li.active a {
    color: #f00;
}

.hoverimg li {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}

.hoverimg ul li {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
    integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">


<section class="">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-xxl-6 col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                <div class="listWrap">
                    <ul>
                        <li data-img="img1"><a href="javascript:void(0);">qwerqwer</a></li>
                        <li data-img="img2"><a href="javascript:void(0);">tyuityui</a></li>
                        <li data-img="img3"><a href="javascript:void(0);">opoiuiop</a></li>
                        <li data-img="img4"><a href="javascript:void(0);">mnbvzxcv</a></li>
                        <li data-img="img5"><a href="javascript:void(0);">zxcmnbv</a></li>
                        <li data-img="img6"><a href="javascript:void(0);">mnbvzxcv</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-xxl-6 col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                <div class="listWrap position-relative">
                    <div class="hoverimg">
                        <ul>
                            <li id="img1"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/fa17fa/0011ff" alt=""></li>
                            <li id="img2"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000000/0011ff" alt=""></li>
                            <li id="img3"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/1ee81e/0011ff" alt=""></li>
                            <li id="img4"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/1e35e6/0011ff" alt=""></li>
                            <li id="img5"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/e6d620/0011ff" alt=""></li>
                            <li id="img6"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/fff320/0011ff" alt=""></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>


<section class="mt-5 pt-5">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-xxl-6 col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                <div class="listWrap">
                    <ul>
                        <li data-img="img7"><a href="javascript:void(0);">qwerqwer</a></li>
                        <li data-img="img8"><a href="javascript:void(0);">tyuityui</a></li>
                        <li data-img="img9"><a href="javascript:void(0);">opoiuiop</a></li>
                        <li data-img="img10"><a href="javascript:void(0);">mnbvzxcv</a></li>
                        <li data-img="img11"><a href="javascript:void(0);">zxcmnbv</a></li>
                        <li data-img="img12"><a href="javascript:void(0);">mnbvzxcv</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-xxl-6 col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                <div class="listWrap position-relative">
                    <div class="hoverimg">
                        <ul>
                            <li id="img7"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/fa17fa/0011ff" alt=""></li>
                            <li id="img8"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000000/0011ff" alt=""></li>
                            <li id="img9"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/1ee81e/0011ff" alt=""></li>
                            <li id="img10"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/1e35e6/0011ff" alt=""></li>
                            <li id="img11"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/e6d620/0011ff" alt=""></li>
                            <li id="img12"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/fff320/0011ff" alt=""></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

**`Update:`**

1. Add class active in both of the first elements.
2. Show manually each of the first element.
3. Hide all active classes and shown elements inside the event.

That's it.

```js
$('#img1').show(); // show the first image li on page load
$('#img7').show(); // show the first image li on page load

$(".listWrap ul").on("mouseover mouseout", "li", function () {

    $(this).parentsUntil("section").find('.listWrap ul li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).parentsUntil("section").find('.hoverimg ul li').hide();

    $(this).toggleClass('active');
    $("#" + $(this).data("img")).toggle();
});
```

```css
.listWrap li.active a {
    color: #f00;
}

.hoverimg li {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}

.hoverimg ul li {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
    integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">


<section class="">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-xxl-6 col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                <div class="listWrap">
                    <ul>
                        <li class="active" data-img="img1"><a href="javascript:void(0);">qwerqwer</a></li>
                        <li data-img="img2"><a href="javascript:void(0);">tyuityui</a></li>
                        <li data-img="img3"><a href="javascript:void(0);">opoiuiop</a></li>
                        <li data-img="img4"><a href="javascript:void(0);">mnbvzxcv</a></li>
                        <li data-img="img5"><a href="javascript:void(0);">zxcmnbv</a></li>
                        <li data-img="img6"><a href="javascript:void(0);">mnbvzxcv</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-xxl-6 col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                <div class="listWrap position-relative">
                    <div class="hoverimg">
                        <ul>
                            <li id="img1"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/fa17fa/0011ff" alt=""></li>
                            <li id="img2"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000000/0011ff" alt=""></li>
                            <li id="img3"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/1ee81e/0011ff" alt=""></li>
                            <li id="img4"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/1e35e6/0011ff" alt=""></li>
                            <li id="img5"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/e6d620/0011ff" alt=""></li>
                            <li id="img6"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/fff320/0011ff" alt=""></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>


<section class="mt-5 pt-5">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-xxl-6 col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                <div class="listWrap">
                    <ul>
                        <li class="active" data-img="img7"><a href="javascript:void(0);">qwerqwer</a></li>
                        <li data-img="img8"><a href="javascript:void(0);">tyuityui</a></li>
                        <li data-img="img9"><a href="javascript:void(0);">opoiuiop</a></li>
                        <li data-img="img10"><a href="javascript:void(0);">mnbvzxcv</a></li>
                        <li data-img="img11"><a href="javascript:void(0);">zxcmnbv</a></li>
                        <li data-img="img12"><a href="javascript:void(0);">mnbvzxcv</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-xxl-6 col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                <div class="listWrap position-relative">
                    <div class="hoverimg">
                        <ul>
                            <li id="img7"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/fa17fa/0011ff" alt=""></li>
                            <li id="img8"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000000/0011ff" alt=""></li>
                            <li id="img9"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/1ee81e/0011ff" alt=""></li>
                            <li id="img10"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/1e35e6/0011ff" alt=""></li>
                            <li id="img11"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/e6d620/0011ff" alt=""></li>
                            <li id="img12"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/fff320/0011ff" alt=""></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

**`Update 2:`** In your case you can hide a specific parent's child by using [`parentsuntil`](https://api.jquery.com/parentsuntil/). Have a look at the updated answer.

Comment: On page load I have to show the first li image. As of now, I am not getting in your answer. Also Click event not working. On click event also I have to show image

Comment: Do you want both images from different sections for the first time?

Comment: Yes, on page load I have to show the first li active image on both section

Comment: @user9437856, have a look at my updated answer.

Comment: I appreciate your help and description but someting is wrong. I have two section (It will increase in the future). If I hover on second section then first section showing empty. I need if I hover or click any of the section then it should be display the respective image

Comment: @user9437856, I really didn't know what's your actual goal. First of all, you haven't cleared your problems in your question. Having looked at the answer you're asking what's your criteria. Before anyone spends times on answering your question, clear your view in your question. It will help you to get your job done. Thank you.

Comment: I think you haven't undersood my question and description. I think you have to check my code which is in the question. Your answer is only for displaying the image on hover. that's good but it also removing other things like click event, displaying image in both section etc.

Comment: You have to check the @Nikhilpatil answer

Comment: @user9437856, by the way, I've updated my answer for the third time according to your need. Check the updated one.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but still not getting my expected output in your answer. I think @nikhilpatil answer is the best to solve my issue. Appreciate your help and description. Upvote from my side.

Answer (score 0):

CSS isn't going to be able to call other elements like that, you'll need to use JavaScript to reach beyond a child or sibling selector.

You could try something like this:

```
<a>Some Link
<div><img src="/you/image" /></div>
</a>
```

then...

```
a>div { display: none; }
a:hover>div { display: block; }
```